# delete data from 2 tables using 1 query

Tags: php, mysql

I want delete all data from tables ( topics and hits_counter ) , topic_id col in table1 = post_topic col in table 2 , i don't know where's the problem .

Code :

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("DELETE FROM topics INNER JOIN hits_counter ON 
topics.topic_id = hits_counter.post_topic WHERE topics.topic_id = ?");
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Add/Update the foreign key constraints in your tables then deleting from the first table will delete from both tables. Also `DELETE * FROM ` is a syntax error. It should be `DELETE FROM `

Comment: @bassxzero: Only if the constraint is defined as delete **cascade**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to mention from which tables you want to delete if there is more than one in the statement

```
DELETE hits_counter, topics
FROM topics 
INNER JOIN hits_counter ON ...
```